# File download from PC to Android device - OutputStream write( ) stucks for large files

Tags: java, android, sockets, download, inputstream

I'm trying to download a file from PC to Android device (emulator or physical)

Everything goes fine for small and medium sized files, but when I try to send something larger than say 10Mb, server never reaches this statement `out2.println("ready");`, hence the client hangs waiting for `"ready"` from server
Seems that server stucks at this: `os.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);`

So far I've tried this on emulator, I'm going to report about results on a real device shortly

Here is my client part, in Android app: Android client sends "download" string to server, then receives "ready" reply from it, and starts reading file from InputStream

```
int filesize = 2022386;
int bytesRead;
int currentTot = 0;

Socket socket1 = new Socket("172.16.6.119", 50001); //data line
Socket socket2 = new Socket("172.16.6.119", 50001); //control line

BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket2.getInputStream()));  
PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(socket2.getOutputStream(), true);

out2.println("download:"); //control line

String usrtxt = in2.readLine();

if(usrtxt.substring(0,5).equals("ready")) //control line
                {
                    byte [] bytearray = new byte [filesize];

                    InputStream is = socket1.getInputStream(); //data line
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sunset.jpg");
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                    bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
                    currentTot = bytesRead;

                    Log.e("DOWNLOAD", "init value: bytesread = " + Integer.toString(bytesRead));

                    do {
                    bytesRead =
                    is.read(bytearray, currentTot, (bytearray.length-currentTot)); //<--does not pull data (WHY?)

                    Log.e("DOWNLOAD", "bytesread = " + Integer.toString(bytesRead));

                    if(bytesRead >= 0) currentTot += bytesRead;
                    } while(bytesRead > -1);

                    out1.println("finished:");

                    bos.write(bytearray, 0 , currentTot);

                    Log.e("DOWNLOAD", Integer.toString(currentTot));
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                    socket1.close(); socket2.close();       

                }
```

And this is my server code: it accepts connection from client, then receives "download" string from it, replies with "ready", and puts the file onto OutputStream

```
while (true) {

                final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();  //data line
                final Socket socket2= serverSocket.accept();  //control line          

                BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket2.getInputStream()));  
                PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(socket2.getOutputStream(), true);

                String usrtxt = in2.readLine(); //control line

                if(usrtxt.substring(0,8).equals("download"))
                {
                System.out.println("accepted download request. sending file");  

                File transferFile = new File("sunset.jpg"); 

                byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int)transferFile.length()];
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile);
                BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
                bin.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);

                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                os.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length); //data line


                os.flush();
                os.close();

                out2.println("ready"); //control line


                socket.close(); socket2.close();
                bin.close(); fin.close();


                System.out.println("file transfer complete");

                }//end if           

            }//end while
```

Comment: You're doing exactly one read from the socket and expecting it to read the entire contents in one go. That is highly unlikely. `read` only reads whatever data has been transferred and is currently available.

Comment: @BrianRoach But I'm using a loop, that loop reads until there is nothing to fetch.

Comment: It will only know there is "nothing to fetch" when the server has closed the connection - which it won't do until the client has said it's finished. Deadlock! Read http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html

Comment: @JonSkeet but how does the server know when to close ?

Comment: Your loop includes *accepting the connection*. It loops exactly once for every TCP connection made to it, then dumps that connection at the  bottom of the loop when `socket` goes out of scope.

Comment: @BrianRoach I mean `do-while` loop in client code

Comment: Basically your protocol is broken: TCP/IP is a stream-based protocol, and you're trying to use it as a message-based protocol. In order to do that, there has to be something to indicate the end of a message. The simplest way of doing that is often to include a length prefix before each message, telling the client how much data to expect.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can't understand why should I include length prefix. The file is in the stream and `read()` reads from it and returns number of bytes read. If there are no more bytes to read, it returns `-1`

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually the code works fine when I transfer something from PC to PC

Comment: the last `read()` simply does not return in my case

Comment: Ok now I realized that if server does not close and flush the output stream, the client never knows where is the end of file. Will try to debug now

Comment: 'If there are no more bytes to read' is only known when the peer closes the connection. If the peer just stops sending, read() will block.

Comment: @EJP you're right, that issue has been solved, please have a look at my reply to my own question below (also its comment). i'm unable to download large files now

Comment: Don't post additional questions as answers. They aren't. You can see the problem. The discussion is impossible to follow. I am now expected to chase you in three different places. I won't do that. Edit it into your question, or start a new one.

Comment: @EJP sorry for inconvenience, i've updated the question now and removed the reply of mine below

Comment: OK well done: see my edited answer to your edited question.

Comment: since 2014 i visited this question again, and while browsing my code above, realized that the reason of read being stuck was `bytesRead=is.read(bytearray, currentTot, (bytearray.length-currentTot));` - the difference between `bytearray.length` and `currentTot` finally reached 0 and hence I was endlessly trying to fetch 0 bytes from inputstream due to `while(bytesRead > -1);` condition. I used the far more compact (accepted) and clear answer below without debugging my own code : ) better late than never

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no way to copy streams. It assumes too many things that may not be true.

The canonical way in Java is as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];  // or whatever you like, anything above zero. Note that it doesn't have to be the size of the file
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

If you know the length in advance and you want to keep the socket open afterwards, keep track of the bytes transferred so far via 'total += count;' after the read call inside the loop, and change the read call to `read(buffer, 0, length-total > buffer.length ? buffer.length : (int)(length-total))`.

Comment: no, I don't need to keep the socket open. But I don't really understand how this is different from putting the whole file onto the stream at once. Anyhow the client will not start downloading until server closes its OutputStream by putting `-1` to it

Comment: maybe you mean that I should read some part, then flush and close  OutputStream, then send `ready` to client, then read some part again, and so on so forth, until all bytes have been read ?

Comment: Ok, just clarify what you mean by `sent`. In my understanding, a byte is sent, when server puts it onto OutputStream, closes OutputStream, and client fetches its InputStream until it receives `-1`

Comment: None of that is true. It's not only different but better, because it works, doesn't add latency, doesn't assume the file fits into memory, or that its size fits into an 'int', ... The receiver can read a byte as soon as a byte has been sent. I don't mean anything more than I've written here. You can use this code at both ends with suitable values of 'in' and 'out', and you should do so, instead of what you have now.

Comment: No, a byte is sent when the sender does a write. If the sender is using a buffered stream it may be deferred until he flushes, or it flushes itself.

Comment: Ok, let me try this now. Looking forward to accept this reply